# How to validate checkbox in Selenium IDE?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-ide

I am new to Selenium IDE. I want to do validations for the checkbox. I have tried the below code

```
<tr>
<td>mouseOver</td>
<td>name=viewIndex</td>
<td>356</td>
```

```
 <tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>name=viewIndex</td>
    <td>356</td>
</tr>
```

It is executing the result as

> [info] Executing: |mouseOver | name=viewIndex | 356 |

But there is no progress on my webpage.

Comment: What is meant by "validations for checkbox"? Are you trying to see if a checkbox is present on the page, or are you trying to click on the checkbox itself?

Comment: when i click at a check box, my selenium must say or should do select the particular check box i did

Comment: That is exactly what I need, but is there a Selenese method of doing that? I grabbed the status using a small script, but that's about the extent of my script knowledge.

Comment: It might be worth asking your own question similar to this one to be sure to get the right tags and people looking at your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used check in command for checking the particular value and uncheck for unchecking the value for it.

As my code goes below

```
<tr>
<td>check</td>
<td>loggerCheck</td>
<td></td>
```

```
<tr>
    <td>uncheck</td>
    <td>loggerCheck</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Selenium Builder](http://seleniumbuilder.github.io/se-builder/) instead of Selenium IDE.   If your script was exported as Java, then you just do this:

```
WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement( By,id('the_id' ) );
if ( checkbox.isSelected() ) {
  System.out.println("Checkbox was already selected: " + checkbox.toString() );
} else {
   checkbox.click();
}
```

I use [this project template](http://djangofan.github.io/maven-selenium-builder/) to run my Builder scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like...

```
if   |   !selenium.isChecked("my_checkbox")
   waitForElementPresent   |   name=my_checkbox
   click                   |   name=my_checkbox
   waitForValue            |   name=my_checkbox   |   on
```

The code above will check to see if the box is checked.  If not, then it will check the box and verify that it's checked [on].  The only downfall to the method above is I haven't found a way to do this with a checkbox using anything except NAME or ID.  I haven't gotten this to work using XPATH or CSS, which would help in the even that the box doesn't show a change in status [xpath] when you check/uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add plugin (.js file) to your [Selenium IDE](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6vnknygMB3ISHBYODA3UDUtS0U/edit).

Go to menu Option > Options 
Upload on Selenium Core Extension slot (user-extension.js)

Second using the Gotoif and Label command.
Full instruction [here](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2013/07/selenium-ide-gotoif-gotolabel-and-label.html) but change the "store" to "storeChecked" because you want to save the boolean of the checklist. The rest is same.

Hope this is helping!

Comment: This is 4 years back question & now technology has been moved from Selenium IDE to WebDriver, Grid, Selenium 2.0 & latest selenium 3.0.
I think no one will be working on IDE the user who posted this question has already accepted the answer, so no need to check ....Hope this is helping!